Why are satellite dishes banned from some cruise ships?
I read on https://www.cruisehive.com/carnival-confiscates-passengers-starlink-mini-adjusts-banned-list/145171 (mirror):

his satellite dish was confiscated due to a violation of Carnival’s policy.

In this case, it was a Starlink Mini. Why are satellite dishes banned from some cruise ships? Is it just to increase the sales of the cruise's wifi access, or is there another reason such as signal interferences?

For most travel providers the top three reasons why they do anything are: money, money, and money. Many cruise ships clearly forbid bringing your own booze on board but are aggressively pushing their own alcohol at exorbitant prices.

@Hilmar: Though that one has a possible non-monetary reason as well: to avoid passengers drinking too much and causing disturbances or other emergencies.  If they're forced to buy it on board, then the staff can cut them off when they've had too much.

@NateEldredge: I've only once been on a Carnival ship and I think they call it "Carnival for a reason". They are aggressively pushing alcohol even early in the morning. The only reason they would cut your off would be that your out of money

I have a vague idea that it has something to do with licensing regulations for receiving television broadcasts. The ship issuing the ban for when you don't have  a licence in a country's territorial waters, and neither does the ship owner.

My guess is about radio equipment ban: it is very generic, and without good reasons, why adding more and more exceptions. Note: GSM ma be turned off on territorial water, but with personal devices they cannot contro such things (and many countries have required access to their gateways). Legally too complex for cruise ships (for little gain). If demand will increase, they may act. Note: dish should also not interfere with emergency signals: AKA: never reflect localizers (and in general low angle signals)

@GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, from the link in the question, carnival's policy explicitly mention satellite dishes: "Shillington shared in his follow-up post that Carnival’s “prohibited” list was vague as it specifically said no “satellite discs.” However, Carnival Cruise Line has corrected its typo, which now correctly states that “satellite dishes” are not allowed onboard."

According to the comment section, the reason why satellite dishes are banned from some cruise ships is to increase the sales of the cruise's wifi access.

For most travel providers the top three reasons why they do anything are: money, money, and money. Many cruise ships clearly forbid bringing your own booze on board but are aggressively pushing their own alcohol at exorbitant prices. Hilmar Sep 21 at 13:24


I don't think a comment from another user, which was stated without supporting evidence, makes for a good answer.

@NateEldredge The comment has received 11 upvotes

I do not think cost matter with Starlink. Maritime Starlink is very expensive (because yacht people can spend much more), so also on Starlink side there will be control not to allow maritime people to use cheaper option of Starlink.

@GiacomoCatenazzi right, so if someone can afford maritime starlink then they could pay for the cruise's wifi

In my opinion yes. But if you are a broadcaster, and you need extra band, but in such case you get a lot more permissions from ship (also because commercial filming is also restricted)

For context: I think maritime starlink is 5,000$ per month + 10,000$ initial setup. So you see a huge money flow to SpaceX which they do not want to lose.

@GiacomoCatenazzi thanks, interesting, I don't know how that works in the ocean indeed.
